# Two way ANOVA in SAS

Tags: sas, statistics

I have a data set that looks like below. I have to find if the scores are different across the four days. I understand I need to run a Two Way ANOVA for this test. I'm quite new to SAS if anyone could help me how to go about this? Should I be rearranging my data?

[image]

Comment: Please post your data as text if you would like any help with it. To work with data we'd have type it in manually and then you significantly reduce the number of people who will respond to your question.

Comment: The documentation clearly lays out how this should work, see the example here: https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=statug&docsetTarget=statug_anova_examples02.htm&docsetVersion=14.3&locale=en

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use PROC TRANSPOSE

```
proc transpose out=...;
   by player;
   var round:;
   run;
```